# Is it possible to make a transfer without the bank knowing?

Tags: banking, bank-account, money-transfer, online-banking, checking-account

I don't know if they approve every transfer, so if not, is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "without the bank knowing"? because some part of the bank (computer systems/databases) will definitely "know", since you request the transfer *from the bank*! And you definitely want them to "know" that the money isn't yours anymore, and that they should send it somewhere else. What are you actually trying to avoid?

Comment: Numbered bank account used to mask the owner's identity, is there something similar?

Comment: *who* don't you want to find out *what* information?

Comment: If the bank didn't know that you spent your money, it would let you spend it again, and again, and again. You'd have infinite money. Is there a way to get infinite money?

Comment: Are you asking about a shell account for money laundering? Well, step 1 is to commit identity theft. The other option is to withdraw cash and move it as you please. I don't think it's legally a bank if it doesn't keep rigorous and authorized track of transfers.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not. It is literally the banks job to keep track of money moving in and out of an account.

Comment: It's even worse: the money only exists as a number in the bank systems,so "transferring money" literally means "having the bank update the numbers". There simply can't be another way,no matter how sloppy a bank might be in doing their job.